# When Hulk crumpled the HulkBuster's hand where is Tony Stark's actual hand?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, when the Hulk crumples the HulkBuster's hand, where is Tony Stark's hand?

..or is Iron man not actually in the HulkBuster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Where is the Tony Starks hand?

Clearly it's still inside his original armour

[image]

As you can see from the above image, the HulkBuster "armour" wraps around the standard IM suits and is **considerably** larger than the original armour suit size.

Essentially, the whole of Tony is **inside the HulkBuster torso**. It's likely his actual arms don't even reach the shoulder joint of the HN armour.